# .NET server error

Tags: .net, server

I'm doing a .NET project and it was woking properly. When I was doing some changes it started to show an error regarding the server. After browsing internet I enabled the log to get the error from windows registry and now it's showing this. I also tries issreset command too. But still it shows the below error when I run the project.
The project can be build and run without errors.

[image]

Can someone please help me with this error.

Comment: It is just a "file not found" error message.  Not unlikely, that assembly has the Chart control and you'll need to deploy it yourself.  Google "asp.net deploy chart control", top three hits are all existing SO questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells you that DataVisualization reference file is missing. Either add the proper ref. or delete the line from your web.config so VS will stop looking for it.

Comment: Thank you. I found the error in web.config and removed it. now it's working properly.